# cakephp with jquery .load

Tags: jquery, ajax, eval

i've got a problem, i'm using cakephp and im loading into a div a page

```
   function loadContent(targetDiv, sourceUrl) { 
       $(targetDiv).empty().html('<img src="/gambu/img/ajax-loader.gif" />');
       $(targetDiv).load(sourceUrl);
   }
```

it work's ok, but in a loaded page i've got autocomplete and thickbox, and that's not working :( when the page is loaded normally without ajax everything is fine. 
I think that ajax loaded page can't see mine jquery scripts.
I've tried livequery but it work's only on something like that:

```
   $("#check").livequery('click', function(event) { 
       $("#myform").toggleCheckboxes();
       return false; 
   });
```

but don't know how to use it with autocomplete and thickbox(made by helper in cakephp)

Answer (score 0):

Your `sourceUrl` should not contain any `<script />`. They will not get executed.

Either move the script to the main page, or inject `<script src=...js />` on the fly when you `.load()` the page.

By the way, `.live()` can help binding elements before you load them.